How can I set matTooltip offset in Angular
I have an Angular application. In one of my components I have an element with a matTooltip (it happens to be an element in a table). My html looks like so:
<td mat-cell matTooltip="Whatever">

The Tooltip appears below the element which is fine for me but it is lower than I would like. How can I set the offset of the tooltip from the anchor so that I can specify that it should not be so far below the mat-cell?

Does this answer your question? material ui Tooltip distance from the anchor

To adjust the offset of the tooltip from the anchor element in your Angular application, I suggest adding a custom CSS class to your component. This approach allows you to modify the tooltip’s appearance as needed.
First, update your template to include a custom class for the tooltip:
<td mat-cell matTooltip="Whatever" matTooltipClass="close-to-me">

Next, add the following CSS to your component’s CSS file to adjust the tooltip’s position:
::ng-deep .close-to-me {
  top: -30px;
}

That will move the tooltip very close to cell content.
Please note that while ::ng-deep is currently deprecated, it still works. However, be aware that it may be removed in future versions. It would be better adding custom CSS to a global file instead, but this is not relevant for this example.

Thanks, Your answer got me there. In my particular  case I also had to add position:absolute. Like so: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rmxdsr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

To adjust the offset of the matTooltip in Angular Material, you can use the matTooltipPosition directive along with a custom position strategy to control the tooltip's positioning relative to its anchor element ( in your case).


<td mat-cell [matTooltip]="'Whatever'" matTooltipPosition="above">
  <!-- Content of your cell -->
</td>



If this doesn't work for you, then you need to define custom Position Strategy. Please have a look to this:
https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview
